# Problem with crepe batter collecting on spreader

Tags: batter, crepe

Ok so here’s the deal, I’ve already read the thread someone else posted about “how can I spread crepe batter before it cooks”. I’m having a different issue and I’m at my wits end. Here’s what I’m using... Krampouz CEBIR4 crepe griddle, wooden spreader, Krampouz round greaser, 14” long thin steel spatula, 230°C (445°F), griddle HAS been pre seasoned as per Krampouz instruction, using exact krampouz sweet crepe recipe AND have also tried the Pancake-world.com French crepe recipe (both from scratch and made to the exact recipe method including resting in refrigerator). After a lite greasing of the surface I pour the batter on and as soon as the batter hits the griddle the first problem begins which is an almost boiling of the batter. Then upon attempting to spread with the spreader, the batter litterally collects on the spreader creating an impossible to spread clumped mess. Yes the batter is smooth before I begin and yes the spreader was resting in hot water before I begin. This happens every single time. I’ve attempted to adjust the temp down... no change. Attempted to add more milk...same result. If I’m following every last detail about this process to the letter, why in the hell is the batter sticking to the spreader??? Oh and yes I tried a steel spreader too... same result. No I am not pressing down on the spreader. Trying to cover all comments people are going to ask me. Anyway, someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just want to like the related question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96053/how-can-i-spread-crepe-batter-before-it-cooks

Answer (score 6):

I have the an earlier model of this griddle, and have made hundreds of buckwheat crepes (galettes) on it, so here's some advice based on my own experience.

Your answer is in your description: "After a lite greasing of the surface I pour the batter on and as soon as the batter hits the griddle the first problem begins which is an almost boiling of the batter."

The griddle is way too hot.  You need to turn it down more.  If you can't turn it down enough to not get the batter to foam on contact, then you have a defective griddle that's too hot and you should return it.  It's possible that it's too hot because you're letting it sit for a long time with the heat on before using it; for some reason the griddle seems to build up heat as it sits.  In that case, wipe it with a wet paper towel to bring the heat under control.

The correct heat is when the batter sets right when it hits the griddle, but does not boil, foam, or immediately turn brown.  As many times as I've used the griddle, I generally have to fiddle with the heat level and ruin one crepe before I can get it right.  In the model I have, the heat dial is labeled 1-10 instead of with temperatures, and I generally have it set to 2 or 3 ... no higher (so probably 120C to 150C on yours).

Snefel is right that you may also be greasing your griddle too much.  Personally, I grease it with 1 tsp of butter before the first crepe, and not again after that.

Comment: Ok I will bring down the heat again and yeah that’s making sense about the greasing the griddle. Of course if there’s too much grease the batter would “float” on the grease and not want to stick. Can’t believe I didn’t think of that. I will try these two things and respond back here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the griddle might be too heavily greased. You actually want the crepe to stick to the griddle at first, to help the batter spread. (Later, the dehydration and starch gelling causes the crepe to shrink slightly and release from the griddle.) If it's floating on oil from the very beginning, it'll just come along with the spreader.

Comment: Ok I will bring down the heat again and yeah that’s making sense about the greasing the griddle. Of course if there’s too much grease the batter would “float” on the grease and not want to stick. Can’t believe I didn’t think of that. I will try these two things and respond back here. Thank you.